# Bootstrap mobile inline form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I' m using bootstrap. I want in mobile elm1, elm2 and elm3 displayed the one next to another (like inline). Look at the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-5 elm0" for="email">Date:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-2 elm1">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        ....
                        <option>12</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 elm2">/</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 elm3">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>2015</option>
                        ....
                        <option>2035</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

However in mobile resolution the three elements goes one after another. If i put col-xs-.. instead of col-sm-.. elm0 isn't displayed well.

What i can do?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the Bootstrap classes and just add following rule to your CSS

```
.elm0,.elm1,.elm2,.elm3{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.elm0,
.elm1,
.elm2,
.elm3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label elm0" for="email">Date:</label>
    <div class="elm1">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>1</option>
        ....
        <option>12</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="elm2">/</div>
    <div class="elm3">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>2015</option>
        ....
        <option>2035</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

But better to use bootstrap class and property.
here is example http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms 
adding this class on `form` http://prntscr.com/6okd0g